# EmptyPage at /HomeFeed/ That page contains no results

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is a very weird Django Pagination problem: My django project is basically a blog website where people can make posts. So here I'm trying to query blog posts that belong to a user and page them. Basically, if the logged in user hasn't made any posts or that he has made enough posts to go beyond one page, everything works and this error does not shot. This error only shows when the logged in user has less than the number of posts a page should have. Why is this so? In case you are wondering why I am using `page2` in my template instead of `page`, its because I have another pagination on the same page, so it's used to differentiate them...

Error points to this line: `blog_post = own_account_post.page(page)` and also says that `During handling of the above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'), another exception occurred:` in my browser.

views.py

```
def home_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user.id).exists():
            blog_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user.id).order_by('date_updated')
            page = request.GET.get('page2')
            own_account_post = Paginator(blog_post, 3)
            try:
                blog_post = own_account_post.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                blog_post = own_account_post.page(3)
            except EmptyPage:
                blog_post = own_account_post.page(blog_post_paginator.num_pages)
            context['blog_post'] = blog_post
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
```

home.html

```
      {% if blog_post %}
      
      
      <!-- FILTERED Pagination -->
      <div class="d-flex flex-column m-auto pagination ">
          <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
          <ul class="pagination pg-grey justify-content-center">
              {% if blog_post.has_previous %}
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?{% if query %}q={{query}}&{% endif %}page2={{ blog_post.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; Previous</a>
                  </li>
              {% endif %}
          
          
          
              {% for i in blog_post.paginator.page_range %}
                  {% if blog_post.number == i %}
                      <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">{{ i }}</a></li>
                  {% else %}
                      <li class="page-item" ><a class="page-link" href="?{% if query %}q={{query}}&{% endif %}page2={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              
          
              {% if blog_posts.has_next %}
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?{% if query %}q={{query}}&{% endif %}page2={{ blog_post.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link"  href="?{% if query %}q={{query}}&{% endif %}page2={{ blog_post.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a>
                  </li>
              {% endif %}
          </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>
          <!-- end pagination-->
      
          {% endif %}
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/HomeFeed/views.py", line 167, in home_feed_view
    blog_post = own_account_post.page(3)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 70, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 52, in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage(_('That page contains no results'))
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page contains no results
HTTP GET /HomeFeed/ 500
```

Comment: `request.GET.get('page2')` What happens when page2 is not present in GET parameters? `None` is returned. Change it to `request.GET.get('page2', 1)` so 1 will be returned instead of `None`. Also in except PageNotAnInteger why are you passing 3? What if there are less than 3 pages change it to 1.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat hey man I just realised that now the 'next' on the template doesn't show after making the change...

Comment: Does  this `{% if blog_posts.has_next %}` not mean you only show next **if there is** a next page.....

Comment: oops, I did some debugging and realised its suppose to be blog_post. thanks!